# Improve performance by using Asynchronous web method call?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, excel, asynchronous

The main focus of the project I am doing right now is about creating an Excel automation function (`CEF`) which allows user to fetch relevant data based on the provided parameters within the function. CEF will populate the cell wherever user uses the following formula, "**=CEF(id, [param1],[param2], ...**"

```
public string CEF(string id, string param1 = "", string param2 = "", string param3 = "", string param4 = "") 
{ 
    return results; 
}
```

Behind it is an web method (`getDataString()`) that is exposed to and called by `CEF` so that it can retrieve results from the database through the web service.

In the original implementation, I used the synchronized approach to call the web method, which turned out to be quite problematic. The Excel froze until all the results had been returned.

So I decided to try to use **Asynchronous** approach here ([the example I followed](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/security/article.php/c9179__2/Asynchronous-Web-Services-Invocation-in-NET-Framework-20.htm)), but it's actually giving me a new problem -- `CEF` always returns null.

```
void getDataStringCompleted(object sender, getDataStringCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    results = args.Result;
}
```

I guess the reason I always get the nulls is probably because `CEF` always gets hit first and thus returns a null string. Currently I'm kinda stuck and don't know where to go from here. Can anyone help or give me some pointers? Thanks very much.

EDIT:

When I was debugging my code, I found that the code for hook-up event probably wasn't working correctly.

```
public string CEF(string id, string param1 = "", string param2 = "", string param3 = "", string param4 = "") 
{ 
    MyWebservice service = new MyWebservice();

    //Hookup async event handler
    service.getDataStringCompleted += new 
        getDataStringCompletedEventArgs(this.getDataStringCompleted); // <=problem 
    service.getDataStringAsync(id,param1, param2, param3, param4); // <=problem
    return results; 
}
```

I wonder if there is any way that I can call `getDataStringCompleted` first, and assign values to variable `results` and then return it in the method `CEF`.

Comment: If the only thing you changed was calling it using an async function instead of a sync one, the results shouldn't have changed. Can you post the code where you call it?

Comment: @Tridus Could you have a look at the post (Edit part) again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that you're returning `results` inside `CEF`, when there aren't any.

```
public string CEF(string id, string param1 = "", string param2 = "", string param3 = "", string param4 = "") 
{ 
    MyWebservice service = new MyWebservice();

    //Hookup async event handler
    service.getDataStringCompleted += new 
        getDataStringCompletedEventArgs(this.getDataStringCompleted); 
    service.getDataStringAsync(id,param1, param2, param3, param4); 
    return results; // <- Isn't set yet!
}
```

In an Async call, you can't return results from where you call the method. It's the event handler that will have results, whenever it fires. In your case you're returning `results` before the event handler has set it. `CEF` in this case won't be able to return a value. Your event handler will have to get the value and the put it in the appropriate cell.

Sometimes when working with OFfice it's a lot harder to get async stuff working correctly. This is one of those times, sadly. I'm not really sure how you'd solve this if Excel needs `CEF` to return a value, because you'll have to block one way or another until you get one back from the service (and the easiest way to do that is just to call it synchronously).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tridus. I am currently reading this article on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) Seems there might be some other alternatives to best solve my issues. What do you think of these provided methods?

Comment: I think they all have the same problem. What you could do is have CEF return "waiting" or something to indicate it's processing. When the event handler returns with a value, store it somewhere and have Excel do a recalculate on the sheet. The second time around have CEF check to see if it already has the value (which it does because you just got it), and you can thus return the correct value immediately. That'll wind up with what you want it to do but it's a bit roundabout. All of .net's async methods have the same problem as the one you're using now, as it's Excel that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks Tridus. I also found some others articles that have more insight into the asynchronous UDF. (http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/01/27/programmability-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx)

Comment: Also I guess one of the challenges to store returned value from event handler is that putting the value into the appropriate cell which is going to be hard. Perhaps need to use VBA or something.

Answer (score 0):

Personally when there is a need of data being streamed directly to a spreadsheet I am a fan of the RTD function. In this case it would probably be overkill though. [Good article about RTD: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285339]

When you said that your function returns "null" - do you refresh spreadsheet seconds or minutes later [F9] and the values are still not provided?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I undertand the question, I think you will find what you need [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/#_Toc173749363).